# Multiple forms to use same function

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I am working on a Todolist in asp.net webforms.

I have the items of the list rendered something like this one after another:

```
<asp:Panel ID="todoItem" runat="server" DefaultButton="updateItem" CssClass="tdLstItemWrapper">
    <div class="tdLstItemInfo">
        <p class="itemHeader">Clean</p>
        <p class="itemDesc">Clean kitchen</p>
    </div>
    <div class="tdLstItemForm edit">
      <asp:HiddenField ID="todoItemID" runat="server" Value="37"/>
      <asp:TextBox ID="empSign" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
      <asp:Button ID="updateItem" runat="server" Text="OK" OnClick="updateItem_Click" />
    </div>
</div>
```

and lets say my update functions is as simple as this:

```
protected void updateItem_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Response.Write(todoItemID.Value + " - " + empSign.Text)
}
```

The first problem here is of course that i cant have the same id for my panel, hiddelfield, textbox, and button for the different items. I could add an ID for each control like so:

```
<asp:HiddenField ID="todoItemID37" runat="server" Value="37"/>
```

but if i do that then how am i going to be able to use the same function for all the items?

I would like to be able to do something like you could in ASP Classic where you could have multiple forms on a webpage where each form could have a field with a name and when posted you could request that one in a function.

Something like this:

form.html:

```
<form action="save.asp" method="post">
<input type="text" name="username">
</form>
```

save.asp

```
<%
Response.Write(Request.Form("username"))
%>
```

In asp.net i could use `Request.Form.GetValues("username")` to achieve something like this, if i instead of using `<asp:>` uses the html version `<input>`. But in this case it will give me an Array of all the fileds with the name username that is contained in my webforms `<form>` tag instead of just the one that is returned in ASP Classic since it is the only one contained in that form, even though it could be a field in another form on that page named username. So in the case of my hidden field where every field has a value this doesn't work, on the other field empSign i could do something like this to get the empSign since only one item will be updated at the time and only one empSign field will be signed:

```
string empSignValue = Request.Form.GetValues("empSign").Where(value => value != "").ToArray().First().ToString();
```

**Edit:**

The reason I didnt use `<asp:ListView>` is that I don't really know how to have solve it. To clarify the page layout is like this:

[Screenshoot of layout](https://www.dropbox.com/s/d859ve5l57ck7cb/screenshot.png?dl=0)

i have three lists:

```
List<todoList> tdLst = todoUtils.getLists(todoListID);
List<todoItem> tdItemLst = todoUtils.getItems(Convert.ToInt32(todoListID);
List<todoCat> tdCatLst = todoUtils.getCats(todoListID);
```

An item can either be root (todoCatID = 0) or belong to a category. Each list can have multiple categories. I do an foreach on my tdCatLst to go thru the categories and to pick out the items for each category i use:

```
var tdItems = tdItemLst.Where(item => item.todoCatID == todoCatID).ToList();
```

But how would i achieve this with listview? If a make a listview and bind the tdLst list to it and loop out my root items, i would need a listview for my categories and a listview in that listview for my items? Or how am i supposed to go about it?

Im a little stuck here. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: I might be missing something - but it looks like you're manually trying to render each item instead of using - say a repeater or list control?

Comment: yes i do. i build a html string and controls and add them to a panel through a literalcontrol.

Comment: Have you thought about put items it into a list and bind it via a repeater, as you then get access to various data commands and you then can use the same functions?

Comment: Allan S. Hansen, check the edit. :)